# jQuery $.post TypeError: e.type is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, forum

I am trying to build a feedback script for the ZetaBoards forum software, I have created a $.post function and when I try to submit the form by clicking the submit button, it only returns 'TypeError: e.type is not a function' in Firebug.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var forumID = '1701794';

    if (location.href.indexOf('/profile/') !== -1) {
        $('table.profile:last').after('<form id="feedback_form"><table class="profile" id="feedback"><thead><tr><th colspan="4">Feedback</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><th colspan="4">Overall Rating: # (Positive: #, Neutral: #, Negative: #)</th></tr><tr><td colspan="4">Submit feedback: <input type="text" name="comment" size="100" /> <input type="radio" name="feed_rate" value="3">0 <input type="radio" name="feed_rate" value="1">1 <input type="radio" name="feed_rate" value="2">2 <button type="button">Submit</button></td></tr><tr><th>Rating</th><th>Comment</th><th>From</th><th>Date</th></tr></tbody></table></form>');

        var profileID = window.location.href.split('profile/')[1].split('/')[0];

        $.get(main_url + 'forum/' + forumID + '/', function (data) {
            $('table.posts:not(#announcement_list) tr[class*="row"]', data).each(function () {
                var userID = $(this).find('td.c_cat-title a').text().split('~')[0];
                var rating = $(this).find('td.c_cat-title a').text().split('~')[1];
                var comment = $(this).find('div.description').text();
                var userHref = $(this).find('td.c_cat-starter a').attr('href');
                var userText = $(this).find('td.c_cat-starter a').text();
                var date = $(this).find('div.t_lastpostdate').text();

                if (profileID === userID) $('#feedback tbody').append('<tr><td>' + rating + '</td><td>' + comment + '</td><td><a href="' + userHref + '">' + userText + '</a></td><td>' + date + '</td></tr>');
            });
        });

        $('#feedback button').click(function () {
            var userID = window.location.href.split('profile/')[1].split('/')[0];
            var description = $('input[name="comment"]').val();
            var rating = $('input[name="feed_rate"]:checked').val();
            var title = userID + '~' + rating;

            $.get(main_url + 'post/?type=1&mode=1&f=' + forumID, function (data) {
                var ast = $('input[name="ast"]', data).val();
                var xc = $('input[name="xc"]', data).val();

                $.post(main_url + 'post/', $.extend({
                    mode: 1,
                    type: 1,
                    ast: ast,
                    f: forumID,
                    xc: xc,
                    sd: 1,
                    title: title,
                    description: description,
                    post: description + '~' + title
                }));
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Here's where I'm using it: http://s1.zetaboards.com/Cory/profile/62973/

Login with test account:

Username: Test

Password: Test1

Comment: Are you sure the username and password is'nt lowercase? And do you really expect people to login to your site and fiddle around in the forum scripts to find an error ?

Comment: The `type` parameter in $.post, why is that need to be in $.extend() ?

Comment: The username and password I posted above is correct, and the test account is so people can submit the form and see the error for them self.

Comment: That I think is the error, it replaces the jQuery built in function `$.type()`.

Comment: Are you saying I shouldn't use $.extend because using it treats 'type' as $.type()? Here's a script that uses the function similarly and appears to work: http://z3.ifrm.com/313/104/0/p366373/form_script.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the jQuery built in function `$.type` with the a value of 1.
What's the purpose of `$.extend({})` in $.post call? That's what causing the error.

Replace it with this:

```
$.post(main_url + 'post/', {
      mode: 1,
      type: 1,
      ast: ast,
      f: forumID,
      xc: xc,
      sd: 1,
      title: title,
      description: description,
      post: description + '~' + title
});
```

Calling [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) without second parameter will overwrite jQuery object's default properties.

Comment: +1 - I discovered the same thing.  Definitely a serious problem.